# DYMO LabelWriter 450 DUO print .label file from Command line

Tags: java, printing, dymo

I am trying to find a way to print a label file(Creating with DYMO Label v8) from the command line. Is there any way to accomplish this ?

(Trying to find a way to print a label with a Java application since the SDK did not support JAVA)

Comment: found already a solution for this?

Comment: Pieter Degraeuwe Yes i did, i found another answer here and modifed the example for usage in my program : ) Here you go https://github.com/simsam7/dymolabelwriter/blob/master/src/sam/LabelWriter.java

Comment: Or well my goal was really to print it with Java and i asked the question with the command line trying to get some kind of tip.

Answer (score 2):

(edit: added more details)
There is a command line tool with full source code written in C++ included in the samples section of the DYMO Label v.8 SDK.

It's called `PrintLabel.exe` and there's a Readme with usage info also.